# I would like to find something like gkrellm for the Mac

Tags: macos, system-administration, remote-administration

I have a linux dev server I watch, and lately its chugging at some points so I'd like to keep a better eye on it. I used to use Gkrellm, but its been a pain to try get Gkrellm to build on my Mac.

Besides servering X remotely (which would not be optimal), I guess i'm looking for alternatives to Gkrellm.

I would like a program that will let me watch the I/O CPU, Memory, processes, etc of a remote server running Linux. I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something simple, and almost certainly already installed on the Linux box, you could SSH into the Linux machine and use tools like [top](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top), [vmstat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vmstat), and [lsof](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?lsof) to see what it's up to.

Comment: +1, it's the simplest and most powerful way. Although I personally prefer htop.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to test Gkrellm on Mac, you can follow this procedure

```
# sudo port install gkrellm
```

If you have this error :

*Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Registry error: xorg-xproto 7.0.16_0 not registered as installed.
[...]
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.*

Do this

```
# sudo port clean xorg-xproto
# sudo port install xorg-xproto
```

And continue install

```
# sudo port install gkrellm
```

Now if you have this error :

*Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_gnome_gtk-doc/work/gtk-doc-1.11" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-xml-catalog=/opt/local/etc/xml/catalog " returned error 1
[...]
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.*

Do this

```
# sudo port clean gtk-doc
# sudo port install gtk-doc
```

And last

```
# sudo port install gkrellm
```

To start gkrellm

```
# gkrellm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Growl](http://growl.info/) for this purpose.  It's possible to send Growl messages from a unix machine by using [netgrowl.py](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/Projects/netgrowl), which masquerades as the growlnotify program, but all written in python.

You could then have a process running on the server that monitors the other bits, and posts notifications when limits are exceeded, or whatever.

It would be a hand-coded solution, but we are on Stack Overflow, so programming-related stuff is the go :)

(Oh, and the netgrowl.py page has a few links to similar projects in other languages, if that's your thing, too).

Answer (score 0):

You are propably looking for a more rigid monitoring tool like zabbix. https://zabbix.org

Comment: The OP is asking for a knife, and you are giving a chainsaw =)